# Understanding Bolzano-Weirstrass theorem for this true/false question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So the question says:

If the sequence ($a_n$) (where $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$) $\rightarrow$ $0$ as $n$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$, then there exists a subsequence ($a_{n_k}$)(where $k$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$) such that

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n_k}$ 
converges.

Attempt: I found this question vague. I thought it was false, and then I gave a counter-example of
($\frac{1}{n}$), because I thought every sequence is a subsequence of itself and thus the harmonic series diverge.

But on second thought, it seems as if the question is asking : "For any sequence meeting the given condition, there exists a subsequence that satisfies the thing to be proven." Or in other words, maybe there does exist a subsequence of ($\frac{1}{n})$ such that the series converge.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it exists. Since $a_n\to0$, there exists $n_1$ such that $|a_{n_1}|\leq1/2$; there exists $n_2>n_1$ with $|a_{n_2}|<1/4$. Continuing in the same fashion, we get $n_1<n_2<\cdots$ with $|a_{n_k}|<2^{-k}$. Then 
$$
\sum_k|a_{n_k}|\leq\sum_k2^{-k}=1. 
$$

Comment: Just wondering. What was the motivation behind finding an upper bound of terms of geometric series? Could I have done this with let's say terms of $\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: Indeed. You can use any sequence $\{b_k\}$ of positive terms with convergent series, and the argument is exactly the same.

Comment: So the crucial idea in this question that lets us do it because the terms of the original sequence are going to zero, right?

Comment: So the crucial idea in this question that lets us do it because the terms of the original sequence are going to zero, right?

Comment: Yes. If a sequence goes to zero, you can choose a subsequence that goes to zero as fast as you want.